SAS EG: Scheduled job CLIENTUSERID not resolved
I'd like to be able to assign a "default" CLIENTUSERID when the SAS scheduler runs. I've tried to use coalesce but it doesn't work:
%LET USER_ID=%SYSFUNC(COALESCEC(&_CLIENTUSERID,'123456'));
%PUT &USER_ID;

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference _CLIENTUSERID not resolved.


Why not use SYSUSERID? _CLIENTUSERID is created by SAS/EG.  Is the scheduler is running the program in batch mode?

You could test for existence of _CLIENTUSERID or just %GLOBAL it.  If it already exists no harm.

How could I test for the existence of _CLIENTUSERID? That sounds like a good option.

%SYMEXIST However Tom has posted a solution that should work well

SYSUSERNAME is the automatic macro variable that SAS creates (as apposed to the normal macro variable that SAS/Studio defines)  But be careful using it as SAS seems to pad it with spaces to 200 bytes.

Just make sure the macro variable exists before trying to reference it.
%global _clientuserid user_id;
%let user_id=%scan(&_clientuserid 123456,1,%str( ));
%put &=user_id;

